# Permissions for a Sharepoint PWA collection site for Resources

Tags: sharepoint-online, access, pwa

I have an office 365 SharePoint site collection for PWA (Project Web app) and when I add team members as resources they cannot click on the "update tasks" link as they get a permission denied accessing the site collection.

I have tried various ways of adding the user to the various groups available and the only way I can grant access for the resource to update their project status is to add them as a "Site Collection Administrator".

I have tried adding them as users in the following groups with no success:

Team Leads for Project Web App, Team Members for Project Web App, Resource Managers for Project Web App, Project Managers for Project Web App, Portfolio Managers for Project Web App, [Site Name] Owners, [Site Name] Members, Administrators for Project Web App. The only addition that works is adding to the site collection administrator role that gives too many permissions

When I accessed the check permissions for the user it said they have full access.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: Where're the following groups ? could you please add it!

Comment: Thanks, here the groups the user is in and still says user does not have access:   Team Leads for Project Web App, Team Members for Project Web App, Resource Managers for Project Web App, Project Managers for Project Web App, Portfolio Managers for Project Web App,  [Site Name] Owners, [Site Name] Members,  Administrators for Project Web App.    

The only addition that works is adding to the site collection administrator role that gives too many permissions.

Comment: Is it SharePoint Permission Mode or Project Permission Mode?

Answer (score 0):

Edward:

You need to add Resource using build Team option on Project Plan where you want him to update the actual hours.

Post adding the user to Build Team publish the Project plan and check the behavior.